# How can i change my username?

Tags: discussion

How can i change my username? Tried something here and there off course but nope. It is now just user 60656 something. PS How can i ever qualify these quality standards for posting a question?

Comment: _“How can i ever qualify these quality standards for posting a question?”_ Try this: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

Go to this link https://askubuntu.com/users/606065/user606065. You'll see **Edit profile and Settings** Tab there. On Edit profile page, You can change your name. Save button is at the bottom of the page.

Note 1: You can only change your username once every 30 days
Note 2: You can just visit this link https://askubuntu.com/users/current to go to the profile of currently logged in user. (Thanks to Dan)

Comment: Note that you can only change your username once every 30 days.

Comment: Oh. I wanted to include that too!, but forgot somehow :)

Comment: You can use http://askubuntu.com/users/current as a link so anyone clicking on it would open their own profile page

Comment: @Dan didn't know it. Thanks :)